# Display custom object field in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my visual force page code,Event_Request__c is custom object, i want to list all EventName (EventName__c) on this visualforce page. i am using this code but i am not getting any value using this code. anyone please suggest me what am i doing wrong?

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0"  standardController="Event_Request__c" >


 <apex:form >

        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact details for account" >

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Event_Request__c}" var="con">

            <apex:column value="{!con.EventName__c}"/>



            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Event_Request__c` is a custom object with field `EventName__c` (as per your note to @Martin.Kona) then to list all `EventName__c` you can't use a VF page on a single `Event_Request__c` as that will display only one event. Furthermore, the `value=` attribute on pageBlockTable has to take a list, not a single string

What you need is to use a standardSetController which you define on the VF page with a page attribute `recordSetVar`

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0"  standardController="Event_Request__c" recordSetVar="EventRequests">
```

and then use `{!EventRequests}` as the value attribute in the pageBlockTable

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!EventRequests}" var="con">
```

Now - all that said, standardSetControllers are a larger topic in and of themselves and it is worth reading [VF in Practice, chapter 4](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) to learn about pagination, filters, and other bits. If you have issues, post a separate question once you get the basics working

Comment: Yes that was the problem, But after doing all this i am not getting all record in column. its returning only 21 record. it should be more that 100. any idea what should be done to get all record.

Comment: yes - that is because by default, standardsetControllers return only 20 records; you need to read up on how to do pagination, filters, and possibly custom standardsetcontroller extensions.  Do some research first and then post a new question if stuck

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify, what kind of relationship this **Event_Request__c** with **EventName__c** has. Typically, your code would look like this, if **Event_Request__c** had **EventName__c** as a childs.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Contact details for account" >
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Event_Request__c.EventName__c}" var="con">
     <apex:column value="{!con.Name}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Are you sure, that **EventName__c** isnt just a custom field? Please provide object model.

Comment: EventName__c is custom field in Event_Request__c object. and i tried what you told me to do but i am getting an error like  Unknown property 'String.Name'

Answer (score 0):

In the above code given by Martin, use **Event_Request__c.EventName__r** instead of **Event_Request__c.EventName__c**. This will fetch you the Name of the Contact provided you pass the recordId as paramter in the url of your page.

https://URL/apex/PageName?id=recordId

Comment: it was the recordSetVar problem. i declared recordSetVar and its working now.